# Webgl2 - The number of COLOR_ATTACHMENTS in a framebuffer

Tags: framebuffer, webgl2

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/framebufferTexture2D), it looks like there are 16 `COLOR_ATTACHMENTS` that we can use in `webgl2`. However, when I print:

```
console.log(gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS));
```

It returns `8` in the console.

I've search on the internet to learn whether or not there is an extension allowing us to use 16 `COLOR_ATTACHMENTS`, but I could not find any. Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to does not say there are 16 color attachments. It just lists constants for 16. How many you actually get is GPU/driver/browser dependent.

[According to the spec section 6.2 page 272](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf), 4 is the minimum required by WebGL2, some devices support more than 4. Checking [WebGLStats](https://webglstats.com/webgl2/parameter/MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS) it looks like the most supported is 8.

Note: According to the creator of WebGLStats the reason that there's a tiny percentage reporting only 1 is because some webpages sharing their stats either by their browser or other reasons are falsely claiming WebGL2 support when they don't actually support it.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. It helped a lot, now everything is clear.